# Rocket.chat css usernames and roles

Tags: css, rocket.chat

I just installed my own private rocket chat for me and some friends and I have customized the CSS to my liking, I visited another rocket chat server and their users had colors in their usernames and roles as shown here

[Colored usernames and roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5pP7.png)

[Even more complex things like username with gradient colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9jvP.png)

I tried asking the admin of that chat but they never responded. Other people told me it wasn't possible but... Clearly, it is. would love some help with this. I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS

The only thing I managed on an older version was to add this to CSS and it would give color to the role name but not the username:

`[title="Admin"],[data-role="Admin"]{color:red !important;background:#202020 !important}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html attribute `data-username` in the same way you used `[data-role="Admin"]` to apply CSS to that username only.